# How do I add an index to Django's User model

Tags: python, django, django-models

My Django project always sorts Users by their first name, and I'd like to create an index on the field, but since it's a Django-defined model, I can't add it into the built-in code. First, does Django already have an index on the first name field? If not, can I add an index somehow? I know I could subclass the User model and handle all of the intricacies with that, but is there another way?

Comment: You can always use your own model.

Answer (score 1):

1. Based on the source code https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L320 , There's no db_index on the first name field.
2. You should Extending Django’s default User to have your own db_index
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user